# Update wsp on a specific web application(with multiples)

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, solution-package, web-application

I have a SharePoint farm with multiple(let us say I have 5 web applications). Every solution has currently the wsp solution installed(we can call it solution1.wsp)

The thing I want to do is I want all of the web applications to keep running solution1.wsp but I want one or two of the web applications to run the updated (newSolution1.wsp)

So like this:

http://placeholder1/ -> should run solution1.wsp

http://placeholder2/ -> should run solution1.wsp

http://placeholder3/ -> should run solution1.wsp

http://placeholder4/ -> should run Newsolution1.wsp

http://placeholder5/ -> should run Newsolution1.wsp

With my understanding I can't use Update SPSolution(because it will update on all of the web applications) I have instead tried to use "Install-SPSolution NewSolution1.wsp -Force –GACDeployment –Web application http://placeholder5/"

and in central admin it looks successful but when I check on http://placeholder5/ nothing of the new code is added.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of two options:

1. In code, check for the Web Application (ID, URL, etc.) and use if/else/switch statements to go between code paths. This allows you to use a single solution for all Web Applications.
2. Create a new solution and port your code. Each solution has a GUID that is unique on a per-farm basis.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. Option 2 is not an option. So, in other words, the only way to solve it is in the code? I always thought you could deploy different versions of a WSP to the web applications in a farm solution.

Comment: You can have a Web Application-scoped solution, but again each solution has a GUID that is unique farm-wide. The GUID is generated for you when you create the solution in Visual Studio, though you can change it as desired.